# How to auto populate text field in angular js based on other form fields

Tags: angularjs, hashmap

I'm giving an student scenario as example.
Assume I have the below scope variables that needs to populated when I select a id.

```
$scope.student.name;
$scope.student.address;
$scope.student.city;
$scope.student.zip;
```

The sample html below.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="student.id"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="student.name"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="student.city"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="student.address"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="student.zip">
```

In a regular jQuery, I would write on change and trigger. But how do I achieve this in angular way.

I might want to have the entire db values in a hashmap of `<studentid,List<studentdetails>>` and use this hashmap values to be populated on the respective fields.

Comment: How do you select an id?

Comment: ng-change should be what you're looking for. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange set that for the id input and use the function to update the model values to populate the other fields

Comment: Does this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/latcZyXWtYEIxuMcWYat?p=preview) help?

Comment: i dint know how to do it when the student data is coming from server in a hash map. Could you please provide that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that hash map?

Comment: say from my server i am returning a formbean which has a variable like hashmap<key=id,value=list<details>> ..

Comment: Formbean? Didn't you mean JSON? Please post the data you are receiving on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably a little late on the draw to answering this question, but I was searching for an answer to auto-population with Angular today and found that you could populate an input using `ng-value` and passing it into your value held inside of `{{}}`.

It would look something like this: `ng-value="{{exampleValue}}`

Hope this helps.